# Where is the correct place for 'type' statements?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I have been playing around with TypeScript 1.4 recently and I am trying to understand the correct usage of [type aliases via the `type` keyword](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx). To add some context, I have a bunch of TypeScript files which I have structured this way:

```
module A.B.C {
    export class MyClass {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And to get around having to use `var thing:A.B.C.MyClass`, I have been trying to use the `type` keyword in various ways, each with their own problems:

### Top of the file.

The first attempt I made was placing these statements at the top of the file, above the `module` statement:

```
type MyClass = A.B.C.MyClass;

module D.E {
    // Yada yada.
}
```

However once I did this in another file, the compiler didn't like that I had the same statement twice across two files.

### Within the module.

My next thought was to place the statement within the module definition:

```
module D.E {
    type MyClass = A.B.C.MyClass;

    // ...
}
```

This worked well for some time, but then I ran into some kind of ambiguity error when trying to assign a `new MyClass` to a class member. For example:

```
module D.E {
    type MyClass = A.B.C.MyClass;

    export class AnotherClass {
        private thing:MyClass;

        constructor() {
            this.thing = new MyClass(); // Error is here.
        }
    }
}
```

Results in:

> Assigned expression type `D.E.MyClass` in not assignable to type `A.B.C.MyClass`

Obviously I am approaching this the wrong way entirely. What is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do? I suspect my first attempt was closer to correct and that those `type` statements just belong in a single file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However once I did this in another file, the compiler didn't like that I had the same statement twice across two files.

Don't do it twice then. Just do it once in a place like `globals.ts`

BTW: I recommend you don't use internal modules ([heres why](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md)) and I recommend you use *external modules*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0

### Update

Don't use `type` for something that you are going to use in *code*. Use `type` only for stuff that is going to be in the `type annotation` declaration space.

To alias classes you will need to use `var`. This is shown below:

```
module a.b {
    export class Foo {
        constructor(a, b) {
        }
    }
}

var Bar = a.b.Foo;

var b = new Bar(1, 2);
```

Again I cannot warn you enough of the hazards of using `--out`.

Comment: Thank you - is there any convention around where exactly this type of content goes? Would you say a `global.ts` in the project root is common or are there more rigid ways to go about it?

Comment: `Would you say a global.ts in the project root is common or are there more rigid ways to go about it`

That's what I do. Haven't had complaints : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/lib/globals.ts /

Comment: Some people prefer `globals.d.ts`. I don't care :)

Comment: So after doing this, I can't create a new instances via the type - it says the constructor does not accept any arguments (e.g. if I do `new MyClass(some, args)` even if `MyClass`'s constructor does in fact accept two arguments.

Comment: Oh, I see now... That is a bit of an unfortunate way to go about it. I am yet to watch your video but I intend to.

Comment: Btw. it seems most of your arguments against internal modules go up in smoke if you use gulp-typescript. It takes care of code ordering, does not force you to use `///reference` tags yet and supports incremental builds.

Comment: @basarat Can you tell us more about the internal modules, somewhere? I am also interested.

Comment: `Can you tell us more about the internal modules, somewhere` Can you quote what I said, so I know what I need to explain more?